# do-while with statement at the end

Tags: java, do-while

Can someone let me know some resource online that **defines** this strange do-while behavior?

```
int i = 0;
do while ( ++i < 1 ) { //this compile (?!?)
      System.out.print("i is " + i);
}

do while ( ++i < 1 )  // this compile also
      System.out.print("i is " + i);
do while ( i > 1 ) {}

while ( i > 1 ) {} //this doesn't compile, the comp. wants the semicolon
```

Sorry I'm missing something from the do-while statement?

On the Oracle official link this is not mentioned at all:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

EDIT:
Sorry, I interpreted a nested while as another statement.

This was the original statement that confused me:

```
int i = 1;
do while ( i < 1 )
System.out.print("i is " + i);
while ( i > 1 );
```

This compile... and is equivalent to:

```
do {
    while ( ++i < 1 )  // this compile also!
    System.out.print("i is " + i);
}
while ( i > 1 );
```

Comment: i doubt that `while ( i > 1 ) {}` doesn´t compile if `i` exists...

Comment: In fact `while ( i > 1 ) {}` is the only loop that will compile.

Comment: What you posted does not compile, you are missing a semi-colon after `while(...);` I suggest you read the JLS: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.13

Comment: The error messages your compiler might throw are just follow up error messages due to the wrong syntax of all the do while loops.

Comment: Where did you find the code you posted?

Comment: Did you compile this code?

Comment: Yes, I compiled the code... the problem was the nested while... Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the oracle link you posted is all explained:

```
The Java programming language also provides a do-while statement, which can be expressed as follows:

do {
     statement(s)
} while (expression);
```

If i copy your code on my IDE (Eclipse), here are my results:

```
int i = 0;
do while ( ++i < 1 ) { //DO NOT COMPILE,Syntax error, insert "while ( Expression ) ;" to complete DoStatement
      System.out.print("i is " + i);
}

do while ( ++i < 1 )  // DO NOT COMPILE,Syntax error, insert "while ( Expression ) ;" to complete DoStatement
      System.out.print("i is " + i);

while ( i > 1 ) {} //COMPILE
do while ( i > 1 ) {} //DO NOT COMPILE,Syntax error, insert "while ( Expression ) ;" to complete DoStatement
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking.

```
while(i>1){}//this doesn't compile.
```

That's correct syntax.

Also the correct statement for a do-while line of code is

```
do {
     //code goes here
} while (i > 1);
```

I think i should point out that a do while line of code will do the code inside the bracket regardless and then check if it needs to be repeated. However a while statement will check if it i > 1 and if true it will run the code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

do while syntax is not right.
In simpler way you should think like this-> do something until(condition)
so here is syntax

```
do{
//statement
}while(condition is true);
```